# Need to select values from a column using a list of strings using pandas.str()

Tags: python, pandas

Need to search a string column values from a list of strings. The strings in the search list are only a substring of the values in the column

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'text':['abc def', 'def ghi', 'poi opo', 'aswwf', 'abcs  sd'], 'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

Out [1]:
    text     id
0   abc def  1
1   def ghi  2
2   poi opo  3
3   aswwf    4
4   abcs sd  5

search = ['abc', 'poi']
```

Required:

```
Out [2]:
    text     id
0   abc def  1
1   poi opo  3
2   abcs sd  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - all values of list are joined by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
pat = '|'.join(search)
df1 = df[df['text'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df1)
       text  id
0   abc def   1
2   poi opo   3
4  abcs  sd   5
```

Answer (score 0):

[@jezrael'answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56338783/3545273) is great, provided the patterns to search contain no special characters like `|`. But you can process every element at a time and do a global *or* at the end. If you want to search strings containing special characters, you can use:

```
df[pd.concat([df.text.str.contains(i, regex=False) for i in search], axis=1).any(axis=1)]
```

it gives as expected:

```
       text  id
0   abc def   1
2   poi opo   3
4  abcs  sd   5
```